# Testing mail from php in OS X 10.10

Tags: php, osx-yosemite

Ever since OS X 10.8 I've used the steps [here](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/12/03/setup-a-testing-mail-server-using-php-on-mac-os-x/) to test sending mail with php.

Basically it redirects php's `sendmail_path` to a .php script that saves the email message as a .emlx file and then opens Apple Mail (and that file) automatically.

This worked well until I upgraded to 10.10

After the upgrade to 10.10 all seems to work, the .emlx file is created as expected right where it is supposed to be but Apple Mail does not open up.

I'm getting the following error in my apache error_log

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/jason/smtp_out/2014-10-22_10.12.20_587.emlx.
```

I've got no clue about what `LSOpenURLsWithRole()` is all about.  I'm guessing this is something around php not being able to open the .emlx file up in Apple Mail automatically (I can dbl click it and it opens in Mail as expected)

I've changed all the permissions as explained in the original site.  Is there something I'm missing that would get the .emlx file to open automatically?  (Does this need to be changed because of 10.10?)

**UPDATE**

As a temp fix, I've reverted to using a folder action but I'd still like to figure out what `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810` is all about

Comment: From experience, it seems infinitely easier to use an API like [AWS SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or [MailGun](http://www.mailgun.com/) to send e-mails, because then you have 100% cross-platform compatibility and one less thing that can break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) instead. All you need to do is configure SMTP to use their server:

```
Host:       mailtrap.io
Port:       25 or 465 or 2525
Username:   your-username
Password:   your-password
Auth:       PLAIN, LOGIN and CRAM-MD5
TLS:        Optional
```

All emails will be sent to Mailtrap regardless of the email address. You will then be able to access sent messages on [mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/), you can view the message in HTML and text format, run an analysis on the message, etc.

[image]